# Isobutene IUPAC naming

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the correct name of an isomer of isobutene $\ce{C4H8}$: 1,1-dimethylethene  or 2-methylprop-1-ene? I have done an exam recently and I'm just curious about what what would be correct.

Answer (score 2):

It will be 2-methylprop-1-ene , as we need to select the longest carbon chain containing the functional group i.e. alkene here.